# Django admin tools and user control panel (no admin control panel)

Tags: django, django-templates

i want use django-admin-tools in a user control panel, any idea how implement?

Thanks you guys

Comment: Please explain more. What do you mean by admin tools and not the admin panel and if its not admin panel then what is user panel?

Comment: Hi JackLeo, Im talking about a private user panel (not the django admin), the django admin is for "administrator"... not for simple users... i would like to use django-admin-tools with a "Private User Panel"....

Answer (score 0):

You mean the django admin extensions?

To setup it properly you can look at the [documentation](http://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#installing-django-admin-tools)

or you need something more specific?

Comment: Im talking about a private user panel (not the django admin)

Comment: Oh, those are django admin extensions, it isn't supposed to work in custom administration panels I think